# SQL SELECT INTO - re. nullability

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SELECT INTO statement copies from the source some aspects of the data definition like the column names, types, nullability, and identity property, in addition to the data itself.

Certain aspects of the data definition aren’t copied like indexes, constraints, triggers, permissions, and others. If you want to include these aspects, you need to script them from the source and apply them to the target.

As per para 2, constraints aren't copied over. Whereas para 1 states that nullability is coupied over. Isn't nullability also a constraint and hence is the above statement valid with respect to nullability? Your thoughts please.

Comment: NO. Indexes, constraint, triggers, permissions etc are objects. NULL is a property of a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a homework question? In SQL Server, while it is a constraint (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862(v=sql.105).aspx), the not null property is specified using column definition. And column definitions are copied over when you create a table using select into. So while para 2 is true about not copying over other constraints, it is not valid with respect to nullability.